# JPA Unidirectional OneToMany relation with common table for two entities

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 tables in my PostgreSQL DB like Organization, Project and Users. What I want to achieve is to have common User table for Organization and Project which holds connection between Organization and Project users.

DB tables:

```
| organizations | | projects             | | users          | 
| ------------- | | -------------------- | | -------------- |
| id (PK)       | | id (PK)              | | id (PK)        |
| name          | | organization_id (FK) | | login          |
| status        | | name                 | | external_id    |
                  | status               | | external_type  |
```

In Users table external_id column will have id's of Organizations or Projects PK and external_type will hold one of type 'ORGANIZATION' or 'PROJECT'.

My entities looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organizations")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Organization {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String status;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>()
    // how to make one to many (unidirectional) relation here??
    private Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Project {
    @Id
    private UUID id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String status;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;
    // how to make one to many (unidirectional) relation here??
    private Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    private UUID id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String login;
    private External external;

    @Embeddable
    public static class External {
        @Column(name = "external_id", nullable = false)
        private UUID id;
        @Column(name = "external_type", nullable = false)
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Type type;

        public enum Type {
            ORGANIZATION,
            PROJECT
        }
    }
}
```

Example data in db:

organizations table:

```
| id                                   | name | status | 
| ------------------------------------ | ---- | ------ |
| 062b7a34-f737-4382-b171-f2a9fcf9763b | org1 | ACTIVE |
| a3e2b52d-25d2-43fd-b5bf-37a0983f8533 | org2 | ACTIVE |
```

projects table:

```
| id                                   | organization_id                      | name  | status | 
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ |-----  | ------ |
| 0d392673-c002-4ec4-9a24-5beb4816db69 | 062b7a34-f737-4382-b171-f2a9fcf9763b | proj1 | ACTIVE |
| f84fda6f-dcbe-42be-9b95-bf11225d1182 | a3e2b52d-25d2-43fd-b5bf-37a0983f8533 | proj2 | ACTIVE |
```

users table:

```
| id                                   | login      | external_id                            | external_type | 
| ------------------------------------ | ---------- | -------------------------------------- | ------------- |
| 985ed43c-175b-4c9c-9f35-434c1b57f68a | firstUser  | 062b7a34-f737-4382-b171-f2a9fcf9763b   | ORGANIZATION  |
| e7de06aa-7585-4935-a811-2d4f6a0cb4f8 | secondUser | a3e2b52d-25d2-43fd-b5bf-37a0983f8533   | ORGANIZATION  |
| 93485049-cb04-4318-be48-27cfa358fbf3 | secondUser | f84fda6f-dcbe-42be-9b95-bf11225d1182   | PROJECT       |
```

So the first user identified by login (firstUser) belongs to organization (org1), second user with login (secondUser) belongs to second organization (org2) and to second project (proj2). How to create relations using JPA? Should I use `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` and how?